# Create an RSS feed from any HTML page

Tags: software-rec, rss, feed, webpage

Can someone recommend an HTML page scraper that can turn a webpage into an RSS feed?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple:

- [Dapper](http://www.dapper.net/dapperDemo/) - Fairly sophisticated graphical interface; pretty good results
- [Feed43](http://feed43.com/) - Less sophisticated interface; I used to get occasional timeouts

You can also use [Yahoo! pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to manipulate and filter the results they return.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Feedity](http://feedity.com/). It's not quite as flexible as Feed43, however.

Comment: @Nathaniel nice one

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of sites that do that:

http://www.mitchelaneous.com/2009/03/25/create-a-rss-feed-from-any-site/